# Do alternative set theories yield the same results as ZFC set theory?

Tags: set-theory

I know that there exists many set theories other than ZFC (like for example Neumann–Bernays–Gödel).

Is there any situation in which given the same statement in first-order logic, if we are in ZFC, the statement is true and in alternative set theories, it is false ? If it is not the case, how were alternative set theories constructed to assure that it give the same results as ZFC ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a broad topic. Maybe too broad for a single question! Starting by having a look at Wikipedia [ZFC theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) and [NBG theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) can be useful. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#See_also) is a list of some axiomatic set theories.

Comment: Different set theories *do* prove different statements in first-order logic. However, we often study set theories that are similar to the *de facto* standard $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Many elementary results that can be proven in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can also be proven in $\mathsf{ZF}$, for instance.

Comment: ZFC and NBG are more or less the same. Precisely speaking, if you have a first-order statement that is purely about sets (in NBG you also have symbols and variables for classes, so basically if you’re not allowed to use those to state your proposition), then it can be proved in ZFC iff it can be proved in NBG.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example would be any [not-well-founded set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory), where the axiom of regularity is replaced with other axioms.

On those theories the statement "There exists a set $x$ such that $x = \{x\}$" is true, while in ZFC it is false (by the axiom of regularity).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Maybe it should be another question but could you please explain to me a little bit why the axiom of regularity is replaced with other axioms, given that without the axiom of regularity, some annoying paradox appear ? Thank you!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge In the link I posted you'll find some details. Are you sure that some paradox arises from removing the axiom of regularity? Can you name one?

Comment: Yes, the paradox that there is a set that contains all set.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge The paradox that there is a set that contains all the sets arises from the (now obsolete) unrestricted extension axiom. The existence or non-existence of such set is not proved using the axiom of regularity. Any other paradox?

Comment: Hmm, I think that the extension axiom only will not be enough. As indicated in Wikipedia (which i find that the proof is true), the non-existence of such set is indeed proven by using axiom of regularity. ...

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Also from the Wikipedia: "In the presence of the axiom schema of separation, Russell's paradox becomes a proof that there is no set of all sets. The axiom of regularity together with the axiom of pairing also prohibit such a universal set. However, Russell's paradox yields a proof that there is no "set of all sets" using the axiom schema of separation alone, without any additional axioms. In particular, **ZF without the axiom of regularity already prohibits such a universal set.**"